# Understanding complicated signatures in alloy

Tags: alloy

in the below

```
sig building{
    abv: Man -> Man
 }
 {
 all m:Man | Above(m,m.abv)
 }
```

What does the below mean? How is it related to the signature definition? Is this a relation for the sig?

```
 {
 all m:Man | Above(m,m.abv)
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called "appended fact", and the meaning is that it must hold for all atoms of the corresponding sig.  So, an equivalent fact for your model would be

```
fact {
  all b: building |
    all m: Man | Above[m, m.(b.abv)]
}
```

In appended facts you can use the `this` keyword to refer to the current atom of the corresponding sig, so a clearer way to write your appended fact would be to explicitly write `m.(this.abv)`, as opposed to relying on `abv` being implicitly expanded to `this.abv`.